What does psql do on connect (that could be taking 1 to 10 minutes)?
In some cases psql is taking ~1 to 10 minutes to connect to PostgreSQL, with no queries that it seems to be running while doing so (according to pg_activity that I think queries pg_stat_activity)
I'm wondering - what does it do / can it be doing?
Context: chasing recent performance issues on our production database that we're using as more or less a data warehouse. The psql issue seems related and fairly reproducible, albeit with no query it seems to run that seems to be causing a problem, so choosing to look at that - suspecting that there is some non-query performance issue happening that isn't solvable using normal "fixing performance" techniques.
Some more details:

Running on AWS Aurora
PostgreSQL 14.10
psql version 14.10 as well
~500k rows in pg_class
~ 130k rows in pg_type
~10k in pg_roles
~600k rows in pg_auth_members (it also took almost 3 minutes to run SELECT count(*) FROM pg_auth_members to determine this, running a "Parallel Seq Scan on pg_auth_members" from EXPLAIN ANALYZE)
We're way below the max number of connections available on the database


Behaviour of other libraries:
psycopg2: it's very similarly slow to connect
print('Connecting psycopg2...')
import psycopg2
with psycopg2.connect('') as conn:
    print('Running query')
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SELECT 1')
        print(cursor.fetchall())
print('Done')

Also streampq, our own Python PostgreSQL library that uses libpq via ctypes, can take a long time as well (but does 'feel' quicker than psql and psycopg2 quite often...)
from streampq import streampq_connect

print('Connecting streampq...')
with streampq_connect(()) as query:
    print('Running query')
    for (columns, rows) in query('SELECT 1'):
        print(list(rows))
print('Done')


In all cases, once actually connected, a SELECT 1 runs quickly.

The slowness of the SELECT count(*) FROM pg_auth_members is baffling.  (It is also ridiculously large, but that doesn't explain taking so long to count it).  Maybe turn on track_io_timing and then use EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)

So psql was a bit of a red herring... it was mostly this:

~10k in pg_roles

And the fact that the connecting user connecting was GRANTed many of these roles, which were themselves each granted many many other roles, which then also has SELECT privileges on tables - in total the connecting user would be GRANTed (counting duplicates) millions of roles/SELECTs on tables.
In this particular use case, the vast majority of these were unnecessary - although we still needed almost all the roles in pg_roles in general.
REVOKE-ing them cleared up connection time (and from what I can tell, CPU and memory usage on the server during connection).
Exactly why this worked I'm not sure - I can guess that PostgreSQL is somehow walking the "tree" of all roles on connect, which in this case would have millions of nodes, and maybe also storing the tree in memory.
